# django REST framework - AttributeError: 'ResetPasswordRequestSerializer' object has no attribute 'id'?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to set-up `RequestPasswordResetAPI` endpoint.

```
# Serializer
class ResetPasswordRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(min_length=2)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['email']

    def validate(self, data):
        print(data)
        # Check if email exists
        if data.get('email', ''):
            try:
                # Get the user
                user = User.objects.get(email=data.get('email', ''))
                print(f"User from validate {user}")
                return user
            except:
                print('exception')
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Email is not registered")
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Email is not registered")
```

api.py

```
class ResetPasswordRequesAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = ResetPasswordRequestSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('make request')
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        print('first line done')
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        # user = serializer.save()
        user = serializer.validated_data
        print(user)
        user = ResetPasswordRequestSerializer(
            user, context=self.get_serializer_context())
        print(f"user is {user}")
        uidb64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(user.id)
        token = PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user)
        print(f"second user is {user}")
        print(token)
```

At the `uidb64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(user.id)` I get:

> AttributeError: 'ResetPasswordRequestSerializer' object has no attribute 'id'

When I look at the output of various `print(user)` statements I have added all over:

`user`:

> ResetPasswordRequestSerializer(<User: john>, context={'request': <rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/api/auth/reset_password/'>, 'format': None, 'view': <accounts.api.ResetPasswordRequesAPI object>})

Trying to understand why:

```
# In serializer
user = User.objects.get(email=data.get('email', ''))
```

Is only giving the `User` without `id` and other fields. When I try to generate token for reset I get more AttributeErrors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in that you have not yet saved your model user at the moment you validated the data.

The serializer method is to first validate the input data, then to save it. E.g.:

```
# first process request data into serializer
serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

# then validate data
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

# and save model, which creates an ID
user = serializer.save()

print(f'Model save, id is: {user.id}')
```

Check out [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#pulling-it-all-together) tutorial of RestFramework that shows it working together nicely, `if serializer.is_valid(): serializer.save()`

Comment: On `user = serializer.save()` I get TypeError: 'User' object is not a mapping. I am trying to retrieve the user based on `email`, I assumed the `id` and other fields will come from the saved table?

Comment: Remove the validation method, or make the email unique=True on the django Models. Then it will work